# How to set [DataMember] on all class members

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, datamember

I have a class with countless members.

I want to use `DataContract` serialization/deserialization and so the class has the `[DataContract]` attribute. If I put the `[DataMember]` attribute that works otherwise it doesn't.

Am I to put `[DataMember]` on all of them? Isn't there a way to automatically set ALL of them as datamembers?

Thanks

--EDIT--

The solution in [Set DataContract and DataMember Without All the Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264748/set-datacontract-and-datamember-without-all-the-attributes) is not working.

```
public Test()
{
  if (false)
  {

    MyClass theclass = new MyClass();

    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

    using (Stream fileStream = File.Open("aaa.bin", FileMode.Create))
    {
      XmlDictionaryWriter binaryDictionaryWriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(fileStream);
      serializer.WriteObject(binaryDictionaryWriter, theclass);
      binaryDictionaryWriter.Flush();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    MyClass theclass;
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

    using (Stream fileStream = File.Open("aaa.bin", FileMode.Open))
    {
      XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas xq = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
      XmlDictionaryReader binaryDictionarReader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(fileStream, xq);
      theclass = (MyClass)serializer.ReadObject(binaryDictionarReader);

    }
  }

}
```

}

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class MyClass
{
  // need a parameterless constructor for serialization
  public MyClass()
  {
    MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "AAA", "BBB" } , {"CCC", "DDD"} };
  }
  public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; set; }<----no attribute
  public int aaaa = 3;<----no attribute 

}
```

Comment: You could do some regex replace. Not ideal but should work for the most part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set DataContract and DataMember Without All the Attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264748/set-datacontract-and-datamember-without-all-the-attributes)

Comment: No, you cannot apply `[DataMember]` automatically to all properties - once you start using `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`, you **have to** explicitly put `[DataMember]` on all those properties you want to have in your serialization

Comment: You can not do it out of the box, but for example PostSharp provides such functionality: http://doc.postsharp.net/example-dataattributes. Another question, how did you you create class with countless members? Autogeneration? Maybe you can adjust template

Comment: @VadimMartynov Colour me dumb but I can't get to make it work the [DataContract(IsReference = true)] attribute.

Comment: @marc_s I think you might be right. And so since I have class A with a member that is list of instances of class B, I'll have to mark [DataMember] all the members of the class B as well haven't I?

Comment: @Patrick please read commants to the answer in linked question: Once you add DataContract attribute you must mark properties you want to serialize with DataMember attribute. Default serialization I described works only if you don't use DataContract attribute at all.

Comment: Fine that's what I did. Thanx

Comment: @VadimMartynov you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393319/datacontract-serializazion-error thanx